# SoapUI Webservice Testing

Tags: web-services, soapui

I am new to `SoapUI`. I have to learn about soapUI ie: How to write a simple soapUI test and how to execute it and all about the results etc.

I have no idea about soapui as of now. So please tell me what is the purpose of a soapUI, how a sample soapUI scripts look and what are all the pre requisites for executing a soapUI testing.

Comment: soapui.org has very good examples if you want to learn. You may also get some wsdl(soap), wadl(rest) on the net which you can start with. While using soapui for automation of API's you may probably require things to be done automatically/run time, for this you need write some code, and soapui tool supports groovy scripts which most look like java or java code itself will run in the scripts. Of course you can follow various forums and post  when you have specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty open-ended question but I'll try and answer it with some basic pointers to get you started.

SoapUI is a good tool if you want to test a service dealing with http calls, like rest or soap.

Create a new project and right click on it on the Navigator view on the left. Depending on weather the service uses a wsdl (soap) or wadl (rest) you can add the location of yours to populate a list of resources defined by the wsdl/wadl that you can then use to start putting together tests. For example if you had a wadl that specifies POST/PUT/GET/DELETE operations, resources will be created for these calls. You can then create test suites/cases that use these operations. First figure out where/how you access the service you want to test, then try and get those resources plugged into a new project and try and make a call of some kind to the service. If you can get the service to 'do something' through soapui, you'll be well on your way to figuring out how to use it to setup full tests.

Comment: are you able to take a look at this question?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390574/soapui-restful-service-questions  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI is a functional testing solution which can be used to create and execute automated functional, regression, compliance, and load tests for webservices created with .NET, J2EE, Perl, PHP, etc.

It does have some less resources online but the [Getting Started Page](http://www.soapui.org/getting-started/your-first-soapui-project.html) on SoapUI helps a lot.